# Too many ports expected in verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl, modelsim

I get an error saying i have to many port connections when I try to model sim, but clearly I have the right amount. Whats wrong with my design ??
[image]

As you can see the error appears in line line 16 of this top module which has 7 ports. [image]

[image]

Here is an image of the other module, which has 7 ports clearly described. Whats going on?? Been sinking so much time into this and am close to losing my mind. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images. We can't do anything with images. Use the "{}" button in the editor to format it properly.

Comment: Welcome new users. Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example will help others help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are there any other modules called EC? Is that the same file listed in the error? What happens if you reduce the number of inputs in the parkingmeter module to 5, does it stop complaining, is it maybe looking at something else? Are you able to elaborate and synthesize in quartus and only modelsim is throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would always suggest using "named port mapping" when connecting up your signals, that way you will be told which ports are missing rather than just that some are. Plus you don't end up with them in the wrong order.

```
EC Third(
    .in(counter)
    .bcd0(bcd0)
 ...
```

Your issue is most likely that you have changed the design file but not saved it - if you are using Quartus as an editor, check for an * next to the file name indicating it is not saved.

The other possibility is that you have changed the design file but not recompiled in in ModelSim - you would need to specify how you are running ModelSim - e.g. NativeLink from Quartus? or manually creating a project in ModelSim?

---

As one final unrelated point, don't save your project in `C:\altera\13.1\...` - I know that stupidly Quartus sets that as the default directory when you create a new project, but that is the installation directory. You shouldn't be saving files there.

I have seen on numerous occasions people saving files in the installation directory, with a simulation folder called `modelsim` that suddenly overwrites critical files breaking ModelSim.